# MBP defaults to bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, reboot

If I reboot my machine and don't do anything it always starts up windows, which I find really annoying because I almost never load bootcamp and it requires me to babysit the reboot.  I'd like to set the default to be OSX again, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of changing your default boot is to open System Preferences and then choose Startup Disk. This will let you pick a new default OS to load.